# Use CSS referenced images in JSP pages

Tags: css, jsp

I am writing a java servlet (struts/JSP etc). I am trying to style a progress bar using CSS in a JSP page but get this error when using chrome's developer tools:

Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type text/plain.

<%@ include file="../include/css/default.css" %>

And in the CSS file:

background:url(../images/bg_bar.gif) no-repeat 0 0;

Could anyone explain why this is and show how I can use this CSS in my page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh... I got where is your problem. You are including the css with @include, so it inserts the whole css file into your html code.

The result will look like this:

```
localhost:8080/GraphBuilder/yourpage.htm

<html>
...
<style>
.myId {
background:url(../images/bg_bar.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
}
</style>
...
```

Now, looking at the address of the page, where do you think will it try to find the image? Exactly, in `localhost:8080/GraphBuilder/../images/bg_bar.gif` -> `localhost:8080/images/bg_bar.gif`.

You have 2 options to solve it:

1. Instead of @include, use simple `<style type="text/css" src="include/css/default.css"/>`. This will make it look for css in the path `localhost:8080/GraphBuilder/include/css/default.css`. And css will look for image in `localhost:8080/GraphBuilder/include/css/../images/bg_bar.gif` -> `localhost:8080/GraphBuilder/include/css/images/bg_bar.gif`.
2. Leave everything as it is, but change the path in css file to 'include/images/bg_bar.gif'. However this solution is worse than the first one, as including css in html file sucks.

Comment: This has indeed fixed the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you get an error page instead of the image. Try typing full path to the image in your browser and see if it works. That is: http://domain/app/include/images/bg_bar.gif

If you get an error - then your problem is that your images are not accessible to the public.

Comment: Ok, try to check if chrome is loading the image from the same path you did manually. If it uses same path - try checking response headers coming when you load image manually, check for 'Content-type' part.

Comment: Ok, chrome is looking here: http://localhost:8080/images/bg_bar.gif and I loaded it from here http://localhost:8080/GraphBuilder/include/images/bg_bar.gif

Comment: It's missed the context and the folder which includes the images. Does this mean that I've got the include folder in the wrong place in my project?

Comment: Added new comment with proper answer.